# Dependency property not change its value after SetValue executed

Tags: wpf, properties, dependencies, setvalue

I'am using third party find and replace wpf control. So when i press CTRL+F the popup should appear by setting it's '`IsOpen`' property, here the code:

[image]

Then it should change the value, but its not:

[image]

[image]

I see this behavior not always, but when i navigate beetween pages than it stops work in correct way.

EDIT: Try to use `SetCurrentValue` , the result is the same:

[image]

EDIT 2: Here is the property changed callback

```
static void IsOpenPropertyChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if ((bool)e.NewValue)
            {
                RapidFindReplacePopupControl pop = sender as RapidFindReplacePopupControl;
                if (pop.PART_RapidFindReplaceControl != null && pop.PART_RapidFindReplaceControl.PART_FindTextBox != null)
                {
                    pop.PART_RapidFindReplaceControl.PART_FindTextBox.Focus();
                    if(pop._PART_RapidFindReplaceControl.FindOptions.FindAsYouType)
                        pop.PART_RapidFindReplaceControl.ViewModel.FindTextCommand.Execute(null);
                }
            }
        }
```

EDIT3: Here is the usages of 'IsOpen' property, set/get only in code, no any bindigns:

[image]

I found that 'IsOpenProperty' itself participate in binding:

```
public override void OnApplyTemplate()
{
    ...
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(this, RapidFindReplacePopupControl.IsOpenProperty, new Binding { Source = PART_Popup, Path = new PropertyPath("IsOpen"), Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay });
    ...
}
```

After some research i found that issue was in using built-in `ApplicationCommamnds.Find`, instead of it i try simple button event handler

```
 private void OutlineTextBox_OnPreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.F &&
            e.KeyboardDevice.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl))
                        e.Handled = true;
            ShowFindAndReplacePopUp();
        }

 private void ShowFindAndReplacePopUp()
        {
            FindReplacePopup.IsOpen = true;
        }
```

And it works nice.

Comment: This is because that property is just a wrapper so you can access it in xaml. You should never attempt to put any custom code in it, as it simply will never get that value. If you need to do something when the value is changed, create a callback action for the static field.

Comment: Actually i do nothing with that, the callback is exist also, and it stops firing also. The provided soruce code is from 3rd party project, i just debug why the popup stops showing after navigating between pages, and found that property not changes after setvalue called

Comment: Check the property's [validation and coerce value callbacks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745795(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Sam, thanks, tried SetCurrentValue(IsOpenProperty, true), the behavior the same, after set i try getvalue and it return false (screen added to post)

Comment: Clemens, thanks for reply also, the property do not have validation and coerce callbacks registered, only property change callback

Comment: Added callback code in post, the callback is also stops firing as i already said after setvalue has performed. IsOpen property not participate in binding i see throuhg the code, just only set/get in control's code

Comment: @igorGIS Did you put a breakpoint at the callback to see what happens, especially what's the value of `e.NewValue`?

Comment: Clemens, yes, after flow is broke it never step into callback. Also added screen of IsOpen usages in project, seems not binding. What cause flow to broke is navigating from MainPage to StartPage, and back to MainPage, so the page recreates, the page load event fired, viewmodel instantiated and so on. Cant understand why it brokes the popup

Comment: Take a look at line 573 of the source code. There's a two-way binding created to the IsOpen property of the `PART_Popup` element. Check how that behaves.

Comment: Yes, found it just a second ago also -)

Comment: Ok, now check how `PART_Popup.IsOpen` behaves.

Comment: PART_Popup.IsOpen remains false after IsOpen of control changes, it seems two way binding not transfer the property change back to PART_Popup

Comment: I found a workaround, if i set 'IsOpen' not in command, but in button click event handler it works, thouhg while debub both command and handler executed in same way, same code executed. but result is different